# How can I determine an algorithm from a table of numbers?

Tags: algorithms

I need help with figuring out an algorithm from a generated numbers in a table. I was half way solving this question and I have already got the sequence for N=6, but I'm still stuck at writing the actual algorithm [image: Question]

[image: conclusion]

Comment: This seems somewhat off-topic here.

Comment: It sounds like the question is asking you to write down (explicitly) the pattern you have detected.  "Given $N$, print ... numbers $(x_i)$ where $x_i = ...$ for each of $i=0,1,...$" and $N$ appears in both the missing expressions.

Answer (score 1):

On input $n$, output
$$
0^2 - n^2, 1^2 - n^2, 2^2 - n^2, \ldots, (3n-1)^2 - n^2.
$$
In pseudocode:

> For integer $k$ from $0$ to $3n-1$, print $k^2-n^2$.